# how would I go about handling these return type errors? (hashmap/table)

Tags: c++11, hashmap, hashtable

```
#ifndef HASHMAP_H
#define HASHMAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum Status{open , active, deactivated };

//template <typename T>


template</*typename Key,*/ typename T>
class hashmap{
private:
    class Node{
    public:
        const string Key;
        //vector<T> values;
        T value;
        Status status;
        Node(string key, T val) :Key(key), value(val), status(active){}

        void operator =(const Node &n){
            string *ptr;
            ptr = (string*)(&(this->Key));
            *ptr = n.Key;
            //Node(n);
            this->status = n.status;
            this->value = n.value;
        }
        Node() :status(open){}

        Node(const string& key) :Key(key), status(active){}
        //Node(const Node &n) : value(n.val), status(n.status){}


    };
    //typedef map<
    unsigned int hash(const string& s, int tableSize){
        unsigned int h = 0; 
        /*each(s)*/ 
        for(auto it : s) h = 31 * h + unsigned(it);
        return h % tableSize;
    }

    unsigned int hash(const string& s){
        return hash(s, table_size);
    }

    int table_size = 103;
    vector<Node> table;

    typedef typename vector<Node>::iterator iter;

public:
    //default constructor
    hashmap(){
        table = vector<Node>(table_size);
    }
    //copy constructor
    hashmap(const hashmap& x){
        table = x.table;
        //for (auto it = )
    }
    //assignment operator //has been removed
    hashmap& operator=(const hashmap& x){
        this->table.erase(this->table.begin(), this->table.begin() + 103);
        for ( int i = 0; i < x.table_size; i++){
            this->table.push_back(x.table.at(i));
        }
        return *this;
    }
    //destructor
    ~hashmap(){
        table.clear();
    }

    //index operator
    T& operator[](const string x){
        int h = hash(x, table.size());

        if (table[h].Key == x){
            return (table[h].value);
        }
        else {
            Node* n = new Node(x);
            table[h] = *n; 
            return (table[h].value);
        }
    } 

    //Node test
    void okay(const string x,int i){
        Node *temp = new Node(x, i);
        cout << temp->status << endl;
        /*cout << table[1].status << endl;
        cout << table[2].status << endl;
        table.at(0) = (*temp);
        cout << table[0].Key << endl;
        cout << table[0].value << endl;
        cout << table[3].status << endl;*/

    }

int stride(int x){
            return (7-x%7);
        }

    //find()
    iter find(const string& x){
        int h = hash(x);
        int s = stride(h);
        int t = table_size; 
        int z;
        //for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        for (int i = hash(x, table_size) % t; i != t; i = (i + stride(h)) % t){
            z = (h + i*s) % table_size;
            if (table[z].status == open) return NULL;
            if (table[z].status == deactivated) continue;
            if (table[z].Key == x) return &table[h];
        }

        return table.end();
    }

    //begin()
    iter begin(){
        return table.begin();
    }
    //end()
    iter end(){
        return table.end();
    }

};



#endif // !HASHMAP_H
```

Everything seems to be working fine except the find function. It's suppose to probe through the vector and return values upon conditions but the problem I'm having is I get these errors about return type conflicts.

```
    Error2error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap::Node>>>::_Vector_iterator(const 
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap::Node>>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'hashmap<int>::Node *' to 'const 
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap<int>::Node>>> &' 

    Error1error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap<int>::Node>>>::_Vector_iterator(const 
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap<int>::Node>>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const 
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<hashmap<int>::Node>>> &'
```

How can I edit the iterator to fix this?
thank you.

Comment: `&table[h]` is not an iterator; replace it with `table.begin() + h`. `NULL` is not an iterator either, and in fact there's no universal "not a valid value" constant you can use for iterators, the way `NULL` is used for pointers. `table.end()` comes closest.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for defining a class within another class? That's not the problem in your code though.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I suggest you repost your comment as an answer. This type of questions are basically asking others to debug a source code for free. Since you took time to look at OP's (lengthy and badly formatted) source code you must at least get credit for resolving his issue.

Comment: @Barracuda sorry, for the way my question came out. I'm not that informed, especially with iterator, pointer, and references. So I was just stumped. But how would you suggest I better format my code?

Comment: @AdamAnt You shouldn't post lengthy source code. Use a debugger to see where the problem is exactly and if you have difficulty understanding something and there's no help available elsewhere or here then ask a question. Your problem could easily be solved by reading the standard library documentation and / or a book on C/C++.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much. I wasn't even thinking about that being a resolution. and thanks for the info about Null and iterator

Comment: @Barracuda I just wanted to provided context in case someone said I didn't provide enough information. I definitely need to do a lot of reading up. Thank you for the advice